# Cannot read property 'vibrate' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Now i'm using ng-cordova vibrate plugin using ionic but it's not working for me. it shows the error `Cannot read property 'vibrate' of undefined` in console log.
Could you tell me how to use the plugin? please try to find out the good solution for me. thanku.

Comment: You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, how would you like to, your computer to vibrate ? right ? It will not work on you PC, console log will says `Cannot read property 'vibrate' of undefined` as you plugin is not running, this will work only on mobile devices !!

Comment: Thanks for you reply my friend, when i checked in my mobile, trigger toggle vibration works good. but when i received notification it doesn't get ant notification vibrate alert. please help me..

Comment: can you give me some code to work with ? what do you have there ?

Comment: Please see the below answer post.

Comment: so according to the official [docs](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/vibration/) all you have to do is call `$cordovaVibration.vibrate(miliseconds);` whenever your notification function runs

Comment: Ya correct.. but i'm using local notification plugin. when notification received i didn't get vibrate alert. and is there any possible to call `$cordovaVibration.vibrate()` in local notification plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using local notification in my app so i want when every notification i get vibrate alert.

**my app run function**

```
app.run(function($ionicPlatform,$cordovaVibration) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() { 
     $cordovaVibration.vibrate(400);
  });
})
```

**vibrate on off controller:**

```
app.controller('VibrationCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicPlatform, $cordovaVibration) {       
  $scope.cancelVibrate = function(vibrate){
    if(vibrate == true){      
      $ionicPlatform.ready(function(){
        $cordovaVibration.vibrate(400);
      })
      console.log('Vibrate Enable');
    }else{
      $cordovaVibration.cancelVibration();
      console.log('Vibrate Disable');
    }
  }
})
```

please find out the good solution. thanku.